# How to close / remove the "upgrade OSX" notification ?

Tags: notifications

I keep getting an "upgrade OSX" notification (see screenshot below) with the only options being to "install" or "details" which provides more info.

[image: upgrade OSX notification screenshot]

I want to do neither, is there a way i can just close it, or better still prevent it coming up in the first place ?

The machine in question is currently running OSX 10.11.6 (latest patches)

Answer (score 5):

Open App Store in System Preferences

Tell it not to bother you (uncheck all)

[image]

Comment: I currently have mine setup like this : https://imgur.com/a/wcDWiGu , is there a way to keep them like this so that it will auto install app updates and security patches, but not OSX major releases eg. 10.11 -> 10.12 and bug me about new major releases of OSX ?