# Postpone Catalina upgrade notifications?

Tags: macos, mojave, software-update, catalina

Software Upgrade is starting to prompt me to upgrade to Catalina.  For various reasons I would like to wait a while, say two months, and I would like for Software Upgrade to wait nagging me until then.

Due to it being a system upgrade, there is no real postpone option in the GUI (I can find).  Is there a way to tell software upgrade to ignore this update temporarily?

Comment: Cant test this, but see if the equivalent in Mojave's Software Update control panel [in Advanced] will do the same as https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/343174/how-to-close-remove-the-upgrade-osx-notification

Comment: And this for the red (irritating for me) bubble on System Preferences dock icon https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344278/how-can-i-disable-the-red-software-update-notification-bubble-on-the-system-pref